# Add a calculated column to a pivot table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, reshape

Hi I am trying to create  new columns to a multi-indexed pandas pivot table to do a countif statement (similar to excel) depending if a level of the index contains a specific string. This is the sample data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['Houston', 'Austin', 'Hoover','Adak','Denver','Houston','Adak','Denver'],
                   'State': ['Texas', 'Texas', 'Alabama','Alaska','Colorado','Texas','Alaska','Colorado'],
                   'Name':['Aria', 'Penelope', 'Niko','Susan','Aria','Niko','Aria','Niko'],
                   'Unit':['Sales', 'Marketing', 'Operations','Sales','Operations','Operations','Sales','Operations'],
                   'Assigned':['Yes','No','Maybe','No','Yes','Yes','Yes','Yes']},
                 columns=['City', 'State', 'Name', 'Unit','Assigned'])

pivot=df.pivot_table(index=['City','State'],columns=['Name','Unit'],values=['Assigned'],aggfunc=lambda x:', '.join(set(x)),fill_value='')
```

and this is the desired output (in screenshot). Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example with a value other than 0/1?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the remark, edited the original question @mozway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
temp = pivot[('Mango',     'Aria',      'Sales')].str.len()>0
pivot['new col'] = temp.astype(int)
```

the result:

[image]

Based on your edit:

```
import numpy as np
temp = pivot.xs('Sales', level=2, drop_level=False, axis = 1).apply(lambda x: np.sum([1 if y!='' else 0 for y in x]), axis = 1)
pivot[('',     'total sales',      'count how many...')]=temp
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, i can have multiple columns with multiple name and unit combinations, so not sure this would work. I have updated the example with a more realistic one.

Comment: thanks for the example, however i need the sum to be horizontal, i.e. rows sum. Furthermore i am actually trying to add columns to the pivot as you've seen in the screenshot of the desired result.

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: Great! I think this should work fine

Comment: You're welcome.